# QtCreator and ncurses

Tags: c++, qt-creator, ncurses

I have a little program with C++ and ncurses in QtCreator:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
       initscr();// inicializa pantalla
       printw("Hello world!");
       refresh();
       getch();
       endwin();
}
```

but when is opened xterm, it says:
Error opening terminal:unknown

It occured in Eclipse...

I've installed ncurses library correctly.

I run my code from console right.

Comment: Do you have $TERM variable set? If not, then try issuing `export TERM=xterm` in xterm right before running your executable.

Comment: Where can I check it on linux?

Comment: echo $TERM # on console to check if it's already set or not

Comment: I got **xterm-256color**

Comment: A quick Google search revealed that it's a common issue of Eclipse not properly setting the terminal emulator. I'd say drop Eclipse for this one.

Comment: However, I have the same problem with QtCreator and I was researching how to solve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Projects tab, Targets, Desktop, Run, Run Environment. Look for the TERM variable. If no found, add it and on the value of it, write **xterm**